# Copying row from one table to another when trigger is called

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I have 2 tables

```
A)
 Table A
     ID | val | 
1.   1    m
2.   2    n
3.   1    o
4    1    p
5.   2    q


 Table B
    ID | val
```

So I have a requirement where when  any row get's inserted into table A the same data get's updated in table B. This I am trying to do using a trigger.My trigger looks like

```
CREATE Trigger tr_ForInserts
ON A
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
insert into B values(NEW.ID,NEW.Val);
END
```

The problem which I am facing is How I"ll identify which row in table A is inserted as I have duplicate entry for single ID.How I"ll detect the exact row which got inserted after trigger has been called. what should be the parameter in query "insert into B values(NEW.ID,New.Val)".....what should be these New value?

Comment: check here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25600/Triggers-SQL-Server

Comment: `insert into B(ID,Val) select ID,Val from inserted` - but I'd query why this second table exists if its just a copy of the first.

Comment: I had the same question as OP and in my case table A is being used as a cache and some records are deleted from it nightly.  In order to ensure that I don't have to bring down the whole service in order to make sure no records are deleted without being present in table B this seemed like the most logical answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_insert ON A
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT B
  SELECT id, val
  FROM inserted
END
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE Trigger tr_ForInserts
ON A
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @id int;
    declare @val int;
    select @id=i.ID from inserted i;    
    select @val =i.Val from inserted i;
    insert into B values(@id, @val);
END
```

Comment: Your trigger is broken. `inserted` can contain 0, 1, or *multiple* rows.