# PostgreSQL: Creating a trigger to copy data from a table in one database to a table in a different database

Tags: postgresql

In the below table, once the my_identifier value is updated to 1 for helena, we need to copy data from this table and a few other tables in Database1 to a TableB in Database2. Also, the data_migrated column value has to be changed to 1 once the data is replicated.

```
TableA in Database1:

name   address my_identifier(bool) data_migrated
josh   CA      0                   0
helena LA      0                   0
```

After update:

```
TableA  in Database1:

name   address my_identifier(bool) data_migrated
josh   CA      0                   0
helena LA      1                   0
```

After trigger:

```
TableA in Database1:

name   address my_identifier(bool) data_migrated
josh   CA      0                   0
helena LA      1                   1
```

Comment: What have you done so far, or what area specifically of what you're trying to accomplish are you having trouble with?

Comment: I am trying to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180885/copying-row-from-one-table-to-another-when-trigger-is-called  . But, this involves tables in the same database. Not sure how to do it across databases.

Comment: To have access to another database you can use a foreign data wrapper.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to move data not between two databases but inside single db between schemas.

In that case you have to create on update trigger with simple insert. 
When all data is migrated you can just drop old schema leaving only new one.